# Is there an easy way to combine two glm models in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have two logistic regression models in R made with `glm()`.  They both use the same variables, but were made using different subsets of a matrix.  Is there an easy way to get an average model which gives the means of the coefficients and then use this with the predict() function?

[ sorry if this type of question should be posted on a programming site let me know and I'll post it there ]

Thanks

Comment: You might find some useful information in the related thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8502/919 .

Comment: In R, the `caret` package has some cool features for combining models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to take the average of the predicted probabilities, or the average of the coefficients? They will give different results, because a logistic regression involves a nonlinear transform of the linear predictor.

A function to do either would be something like this. Set `avg` to `"prob"` to get the former, or something else for the latter.

```
pred_comb <- function(mod1, mod2, dat, avg="prob", ...)
{
    xb1 <- predict(mod1, dat, type="link", ...)
    xb2 <- predict(mod2, dat, type="link", ...)
    if(avg == "prob")
        (plogis(xb1) + plogis(xb2))/2
    else plogis((xb1 + xb2)/2)
}
```

Comment: @Hong Ooi:  Thanks!  This code is really useful, and will do the trick, but what I was mainly aiming for was a function which would give a new R model which I could then put into predict() later on in the workflow.  However, I think your function is pretty elegant, and like the way you can set it to give probabilities.

Comment: @Andrew you can take advantage of R's object-oriented programming for this. Put your two models into a list, and give it a class, say `glm_2`. Call the above function `predict.glm_2` and you can then use `predict()` on your object as required.

Comment: Why is averaging the coefficients appropriate?  If the two datasets have different sizes, then surely at least some form of weighted average should be used.

Comment: @ Hong - thanks, I'll try this out. @whuber - thanks for pointing this out.  If my two datasets are the same size, is weighting an issue (I hadn't thought of this before).  If they are different do I just weight by the ratio of the sizes (e.g. the if one is twice as big, do I give it twice the weight)?

Comment: @Andrew It is correct to weight by data count only if the values of the independent variables are the same in both subsets.  For a better approach (which is also theoretically valid), see the thread I referenced in a comment to your question.