# Can you combined two sources with difference variance to reduce error?

Tags: estimation, variance, covariance-matrix

I have two samples of data each estimates of a position `x, y` with Gaussian noise. One source has a larger variance than the other. Is this source in any way useful in providing a better estimate of the true position than the source with lower variance or should it just be discounted?

Comment: Do you know thwe variances -- or the ratio of the variances?

Comment: More information is also available at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5392 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8502 (which solves a generalization of this problem: the estimator is given by regressing the data against a constant).

Comment: @Russ Lenth Yes they are known.